# Mac OS X 10.9.3 Default Window Size for Screenflow

Tags: macos

How can I set the default window size so that each time I open a ScreenFlow document, it is the same size and position on the screen?

Answer (score 0):

According to research, it's not yet a feature and is not currently possible. - [Source](http://forum.telestream.net/forum/messageview.aspx?catid=42&threadid=15598) from the  ScreenFlow community/support forums.

Response from a community Moderator and it's a post from earlier this year.